# How could I generate a document that catalogs a collection of 3D models?

Tags: 3d, tools, resource-management

I have a lot of 3D models (.obj and .fbx) I can re-use in some games, but sometimes I forget them.

So I want to create a (for instance) Word document with the images of all my 3D models.

This can be useful to organize & reuse models from my personal library.

I know I could do this by hand, but that's not efficient; how could I somehow automate some parts of the process to achieve this?

Comment: @stighy so you'd like to find a way to 1) scan for model files on your computer 2) somehow have a screenshot taken of them and 3) gather all of these screenshots and add them to a word document (for instance). Is that what you're after? Making some kind of catalogue of your model files?

Comment: @alexandre Vaillancourt: yes, this is what i want to do. But it's not mandatory an automatic way... I can do manually, but something better than : open 3d model, take screenshot, paste on a word document...

Comment: @stighy This seems like something you could do with scripting in some 3d modeling programs. But you aren't telling us which one you are using, so we can't answer your question.

Comment: Maybe a better way to go about this would be to generate preview images of each new model you make, and then save those along with the model file itself.  Then, you could view the folder where you store all those unused models in some browser which lets you view and thumbnail images.

Comment: It could also be helpful to be very, very descriptive when naming the files of your models.

Comment: Knowing what modelling programs & file formats you're using could be very useful for getting high-quality answers to this question.

Comment: Obj and Fbx for instance